# how to compress code in .json file in IDEA?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

IDEA makes the code in the `.json` file easier to read by adding appropriate line breaks and indentation, but I now want to ask IDEA to compress the JSON content to the extreme (without any indentation and line breaks). What should I do?

Comment: There is no code in a .json file. It is all data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA doesn't have any built-in plugins for that. You can try the solutions available on the web, [json-minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-minify) package, for example.
It can then be set up as [external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/configuring-third-party-tools.html) or a [file watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/using-file-watchers.html) to be run from the IDE

Answer (score 39):

With IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 (Ultimate Edition) at least, you can simply do:

Select-All,
Edit > Join Lines

(Windows: ctrl-A, ctrl-shift-J with default mapping.)
This places everyting on one line, so no indentation or linebreaks.  However, there will be a after commas and before/after colons, if your code style is set for that.

Comment: this is a life saver! enough with the json online editors.. IntelliJ has it all!

Comment: ctrl-r, spacebar, replace all and space's are gone too
(feel free to regex replace all whitespace )

Comment: @ArjanW: This would also eliminate any spaces in text:  "Hello World" becomes "HelloWorld".  I don't think this is what the original poster would want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not so good at remembering shortcut mappings, you have the option of installing [JSON Formatter plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13931-json-formatter) which allow you to minify and format and also verify a JSON file.